# Actualización base de Datos SQL mediante Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Me encuentro realizando mi proyecto para fin de semestre, con lo cual uno mi proyecto con una base de datos de un servidor local (localhost), para esto requiero que cuando un usuario inicie sesión su estado cambie de 0 a 1 representando un boolean y queriendo decir que se encuentra activo, esto lo hago en el código cuando el inicio de sesión es exitoso, sin embargo la actualización no se ve reflejada en la base de datos.

```
try{
    Connection nc = Conexion.conectar();
    PreparedStatement pts=nc.prepareStatement("update usuarios set Estado = ?  where Usuario = "+usuario.getText().trim());
        pts.setString(1, "1");
        pts.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("perdon");
    }
```

La tabla se llama `usuarios` y la columna que requiero actualizar es `Estado`, los nombres de ambas se encuentran bien escritos, en la excepción puse eso para poder identificar en mis distintos intentos si funcionó o no sin tener que estar revisando la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Has probado nc.createStatement en lugar de prepareStatement?

Comment: Hola! Prueba usando `e.printStackTrace()` en el bloque catch para ver el motivo del error y no sólo a tu código pidiendo disculpas :) Luego, trae esa traza de error y la añades a la pregunta yendo a [edit]